# Laravel installation problem

Tags: 14.04

while installing laravel i have following error in terminal.How to fix problem??:[image]

Answer (score 0):

I do not think that this error is directly laravel related but rather has to do with your environment.

Open a terminal window and type:

`sudo a2enmod rewrite`
`sudo apache2ctl graceful`

This will ensure that the rewrite module is enabled, and restart the apache server to ensure the module is active.

If that does not work you should try this:
`sudo rm /etc/apache2/mods-enabled/rewrite.load`
`sudo a2enmod rewrite`
`sudo service apache2 restart`